# Why can I not override a layout in my rails mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm specifying layout 'email_no_padding' at the top of my OrderMailer, but it always seems to look for layouts/email. How can I correctly override this template?

**Error:**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplateError
Missing template layouts/email with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. 
Searched in: 
* "/Users/macuser/github/railsapp/app/views" 
* "/Users/macuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise_invitable-1.0.1/app/views" 
* "/Users/macuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views" 
* "/Users/macuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/kaminari-eb1c080b9999/app/views"
```

**Mailer:**

```
class OrderMailer < BaseMailer

  layout 'email_no_padding'

  helper Members::OrdersHelper

  def notify_member_and_expert_of_birthday_gift_delivery(order_id)
    @order = Order.find(extract_id(order_id))
    @member = @order.member
    @expert = @order.andand.expert || @member.andand.expert
    mail(
      :subject  => "An Elephant Never Forgets...",
      :to       => @member.email,
      :cc       => @expert && @expert.email,
      :tag      => 'birthday_delivery-notification'
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: can you paste your mailer code please?

Comment: Looks like you've done it correct. It may be a typo. Paste mailer code.

Comment: Is there something weird in your orders_helper which is overwriting the layout?

Comment: My guess is, it's looking for the email template in your BaseMailer class